# Edit String Variable in Flutter

Tags: variables, dart, flutter

how to edit value of `messagePrefs` variable.
in this my code :

```
Future<List<ChatTile>> fetchChat(socketutil,id) async {
  Completer completer = new Completer();
  String messagePrefs = '[]';
  socketutil.join(id)
  .then((result) async {
    print("DUA");
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    messagePrefs = (prefs.getString('messagePrefs') ?? "[]");
    print(messagePrefs); value is '[{"createdAt":"2018-09-07T15:24:26.280Z","is_read":1,"_id":"5b92982a5d31755e82288456","from_id":"5b751f8a052e8b0a19f1c684","from_name":"RITA .L. Bubun","from_photo":"https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-Nocv8SNhvn0\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAALk\/nwOSRVOuPKg\/photo.jpg","from_device":"Mobile Phone","text":"Assalamualaikum, mohon kiranya kami dapat diinformasikan terkait dokumen akreditasi prodi, apabila kami telah mengirim dokumen dengan mengisi SAPTO online, dan kemudian masih ad perbaikan dan perbaikan tersebut dikirim pada bulan Oktober, apakah prodi tersebut akan terkena aturan pemberlakuan 9 standar atau tetap menggunakan 7 standar sesuai pengajuan sebelum Oktober"}]'
    completer.complete(result);
  })
  .catchError((e) {
    print(e);
  });
  print(messagePrefs); //value is '[]'
  return await compute(parseListChat, messagePrefs);
}
```

what can i do, to change the value of `messagePrefs` variable?

thank you, best regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the value, but that happens after the print statement has been executed.

Try adding an `await` before `socketUtil.join(id).then( ... )` to wait for that operation to complete before continuing to the print statement.

Even better, use `await` consistently instead of mixing it with `then` calls:

```
Future<List<ChatTile>> fetchChat(socketutil,id) async {
  String messagePrefs = '[]';
  try {
    var result = await sockeutil.join(id);
    print("DUA");
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    messagePrefs = (prefs.getString('messagePrefs') ?? "[]");
    print(messagePrefs);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print(messagePrefs);
  return await compute(parseListChat, messagePrefs);
}
```

(I didn't see any use of `completer` so I removed it too).

Comment: thank for your comment @lrn, i will try.. best regard